# Why does Joomla add category id's to aliases?

Tags: mysql, joomla, menu, alias, categories

thanks for reading my question. I am building a Joomla 3.1 site with quite an elaborate menuing scheme. The strangest thing is happening regarding aliases for one particular category level. For an example, these are the category links contained in my displayed menu (as I intend them to appear using aliases):

myurl/888000
myurl/888000/8881007
myurl/888000/8881007/9273
myurl/888000/8881007/9273/100
myurl/888000/8881007/9273/100/**AHS**

The categories' pages display as expected using these aliases until the last category of "/AHS". I get a 404 error with this alias.

On its parent category page "myurl/888000/8881007/9273/100", the last category displays with the following path: /888000/8881007/9273/100/**888657283-AHS**......and this one woks!

I'm perplexed as to why this is. The category_id is suddenly appearing as a prefix to the alias *for just this category level*. Can anyone share an explanation on what is causing this?

Update: One other strange thing to note- most of these menuing records were added directly to the MySQL database _categories and _menu tables. If I go into the Joomla Admin page and manually update & save this category's alias with the exact same "AHS" value, the "myurl/888000/8881007/9273/100/**AHS**" link suddenly works.

????????????

Thanks in advance for the help-

Tim

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realize there was a Joomla specific site, thanks for the suggestion